# Implementing nodemailer with Angular-Seed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodemailer

I'm frustrated and have exhausted what I believe to be good google searches.  I am creating a web app and used Angular Seed as my starting point.  This project uses http-server.  I've created several views/controllers/etc.  One of my views has a contact form.  I thought I could easily add nodemailer to enable me to send the form as an email.  That was a big fat fail.  I see a lot of examples online telling me to add the nodemailer code to app.js but I keep getting errors saying require is undefined.  I'm not sure what else to do. Here's what I've got going on:

app.js:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'sn.skrollr',
  'ng.picturefill',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'myApp.version'
]).config(["snSkrollrProvider", function(snSkrollrProvider) {
  snSkrollrProvider.config = { smoothScrolling: true,};
}]);

//initialise skrollr at runtime
myApp.run(["snSkrollr", function(snSkrollr) {
  snSkrollr.init();
  console.log("in init ");
}]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when("/homePage", {
        templateUrl: "Views/homePage.html",
        json: 'json/home.json',
        controller: 'homeController'
    }).
    when("/ourMission", {
        templateUrl: "Views/mission.html",
        json: 'json/mission.json',
        controller: 'ourMissionController'

    }).
    when("/achievements", {
        templateUrl: "Views/achievements.html",
        json: 'json/achievements.json',
        controller: 'achievementsController'

    }).
    when("/whoWeAre", {
        templateUrl: "Views/whoWeAre.html",
        json: 'json/whoWeAre.json',
        controller: 'whoWeAreController'

    }).
    when("/contact", {
        templateUrl: "Views/contact.html",
        json: 'json/contact.json',
        controller: 'contactUsController'

    }).
    when("/globalNav", {
        templateUrl: "Navigation/bandedNavTemplate.html",
        controller: 'bandedNavControl',
        json: 'json/globalNav.json'

    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/homePage'})
}]);
})();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "C4P",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "C4P ",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
  "bower": "^1.3.1",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-concat-css": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0",
  "http-server": "^0.6.1",
  "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
  "karma": "~0.12",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
  "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.6",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
  "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "^2.1.0",
  "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
},
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install",
  "prestart": "npm install",
  "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
  "pretest": "npm install",
  "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
  "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js  --single-run",
  "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
  "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
  "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
  "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
  "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i',   /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + sed(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/,'sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map','app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
},
"dependencies": {
  "nodemailer": "^2.3.0"
}
```

}

If I try adding the following into app.js I get errors:

```
'use strict'
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
service: "Gmail",  // sets automatically host, port and connection security     settings
   auth: {
      user: "user@gmail.com",
     pass: "12346Guuhf."
 }
});

smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
   from: "Sender P <email@gmail.com>", // sender address.  Must be the same as     authenticated user if using Gmail.
 to: "Receiver Name <receiver@email.com>", // receiver
 subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
 text: "Email Example with nodemailer" // body
}, function(error, response){  //callback
 if(error){
   console.log(error);
 }else{
   console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
 }

 smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
```

});

Am I adding this code to the wrong area?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: That's only client side code (Angular), you need to add the server side (Node.js) one and place that code there.

Comment: I suppose I'm not quite following you.  I've installed the nodemailer node module with npm.  Are you saying I need to add more code in addition to that?

Comment: Ok I think I know my issue now.  I was adding the node modules in the wrong directory, which caused me to get errors about "require" being undefined.

Comment: Why not add all this in another Js file  example mailer.Js and just var mailer = require('/mailer'); makes your app.js look clean.thank you

Comment: ah...thats a good idea too.  Thanks sac Dahal :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should distinguish between the client-side (your angular code) and the server-side (your node.js) code. In your example it looks like you are using the nodejs code in your angular app, which will not work.

Once your server-side is hosted (see instructions from [here](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201601221424994/email-composer-send-emails-with-nodejs-and-mailgun)), then you call it from your client-side with `$http` (in angular).

On the server-side I recommend that you set it up using Express so you can handle the routes (thus accept the parameters such as `senderEmail`, `senderName`, `html`, etc. You can find a [full example](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201601221424994/email-composer-send-emails-with-nodejs-and-mailgun) in Angular (using $http) and an Express Setup with NodeJS with Nodemailer as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks JohnAndrews...I've only done front end type work and I definitely had a hard time understanding the difference between client and server side...